# Запись объекта класса в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, классы

Прочитал это:
[Запись string в бинарый файл . С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650106/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-string-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%A1)

Поясняю - открываю отдельный вопрос, потому что репутации не хватает на комменты 8(

Респект Harry - смотрю, часто отвечает. Плиз, поясните, а почему вообще возникает проблема со считыванием полей класса string? Подозреваю, из-за непредсказуемой длины строк, но хотелось бы знать точно.

Именно поэтому Harry советует записывать предварительно длину в инт/переменную и считывать каждое поле класса отдельно?

И еще одно уточнение - значит, методы write/read из библиотек fstream'а можно использовать только для классов со стандартными полями (типа int, double) а для string и char* нужно писать переопределённые методы/друж-функции?

Comment: блин, пока писал вопрос, наполовину разобрался сам)) Но ответов жду. Еще хотел бы уточнить - обязательно файл открывать в бинарном? Можно ведь и в текст записать?

Comment: Есть такое понятие - сериализация. Как раз и занимается тем что превращает объекты в нечто, что можно записать в файл, а потом оттуда восстановить. Можно, например, сериализовать в JSON, и записывать в текст, а можно использовать Google Protobuf, и тогда в бинарном виде сохранить объект

Comment: Строку - если это чисто текстовая строка - можно и писать-читать до нулевого заключительного символа. Но `string` в общем случае может содержать и нулевые символы. Поэтому приходится хранить и длину строки, и содержимое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим, что такое класс string, но в пока в идеализированном состоянии. Это просто структура, которая хранит размер строки, указатель на нее и емкость строки (то есть, реальный размер буфера, на который указывает строка).

В этот момент уже должно быть тревожно - там есть указатель! И сохраняя просто переменную типа string в файл как структуру (а ее размер оказывается обычно 32 байта), мы сохраняем размер, емкость (capacity) и указатель. После перезапуска программы этот указатель будет показывать в пустоту или куда то, где об  этом не будут знать.

Почему так? да просто при подобном сохранении сохраняются только байты, они не знают о внутренней логике программы.

Почему иногда это все таки работает, не смотря на указатель? Во первых, часто тестируют не закрывая программу. В этом случае есть большая вероятность (ещё раз - гарантий нет, а только вероятность), что данные по указателю не будут испорчены.

Во вторых, есть такая штука, как [SSO - small string optimization](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/) - оптимизация маленьких строк. Если строка небольшого размера (5-10 символов), то ее можно вместить прямо внутри структуры там, где хранится указатель-емкость. В теории можно запихнуть до 31 байта (если вся структура 32 байта - один битик нужен как флажок). И вот такая строка должна сохраниться и восстановится нормально -  у нее нет "внешних буферов".

Теперь перейдем ближе к вопросу. Так как размер string в байтах не меняется (а иначе было бы невозможно объявить переменную класса типа string - компилятор бы не знал, сколько памяти выделять), то и при десериализации нужно знать размер строки, чтобы знать, сколько читать.

> методы write/read из библиотек fstream'а можно использовать только для классов со стандартными полями (типа int, double) а для string и char* нужно писать переопределённые методы/друж-функции?

этими функциями можно писать pod типы. А string таким не является. (точнее, он иногда может быть таким - sso). По другому - если переменные класса не являются явными или неявными указателями (класс/структура имеет внешние данные), то для такого типа нужно писать специализированный сериализатор/десериализатор).