# Проблема сравнения элемента массива с числом (массив является частью динамического массива структур)

Tags: c++, структуры, проверка, динамические-структуры

Задание:

> Создать бинарный файл, компонентами которого является структура со следующими полями:
> фамилия и инициалы студентов, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из трех дисциплин), размер стипендии.
> Переписать бинарный файл так, чтобы для студентов, у которых нет троек, размер стипендии должен быть увеличен на 30%.

Так вот, у меня возникла проблема с проверкой, есть ли в массиве успешности оценки больше 3.

Мой код(он ещё до конца не дописан, меня застопорило только это сравнение):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    string FIO;
    string Group;
    int AcademicPerformance[3];
    int Scholarship_size;
    void readInfo();
    void outputInfo();
};

void Student::readInfo()
{
    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    cout << "Input FIO: ";
    getline(cin, FIO, '\n');

    cout << "Input Group: ";
    getline(cin, Group, '\n');

    cout << "Input Academic performance: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cin >> AcademicPerformance[i];
    }

    cout << "Input scholarship size: ";
    cin >> Scholarship_size;
}

void Student::outputInfo()
{
    cout << "FIO: " << FIO << endl;
    cout << "Group: " << Group << endl;
    cout << "Academic Performance: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << AcademicPerformance[i] << setw(3);
    }
    cout << "\nScholarship size: " << Scholarship_size << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Input the number of students: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    Student* student = new Student[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        student[i].readInfo();
        cout << endl;
    }
    char fileName[] = "StudentInfo.bin";
    FILE* file_1, * file_2;
    file_1 = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    fwrite(student, sizeof(Student), number, file_1);
    fclose(file_1);

    Student* studentInfo = new Student[number];
    file_2 = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fread(studentInfo, sizeof(Student), number, file_2);
    fclose(file_2);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (studentInfo[j].AcademicPerformance > 3)
            {
                studentInfo[i].Scholarship_size = studentInfo[i].Scholarship_size + (studentInfo[i].Scholarship_size * 0.3);
            }
        }
        studentInfo[i].outputInfo();
    }
}
```

Вот в этом фрагменте

```
if (studentInfo[j].AcademicPerformance > 3)
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Несовместимые типы операндов ("int* и int")

Честно, я не очень понимаю как в таком случае проводить проверку, поэтому надеюсь на подсказку опытных программистов.

Comment: Задайте себе вопрос: каков тип операнда слева от > и какой - справа.

Comment: studentInfo[j].AcademicPerformance[какойтоиндекс]

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнить сразу весь массив из трёх элементов с числом. Сравнивайте в цикле каждый элемент массива с числом: `studentInfo[i].AcademicPerformance[j]`. Но у вас тут есть проблема посерьёзнее. Вы пишете/читаете в файл побайтово структуру, хранящую экземпляры не тривиально-копируемого  класса `std::string`. Так нельзя. См.: [Запись объекта класса в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816254).

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то ты возвращаешь указатель. Тебе просто нужно разыминвать его, при получении.

-Вместо

> studentInfo[j].AcademicPerformance > 3

Пиши

`*studentInfo[j].AcademicPerformance > 3`