# Запись объекта в файл без лишних символов

Tags: c++

Изучаю запись/чтение данных в файл и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Записываю объект в файл через методы read/write.

```
vector<PhoneBook> data;

while (inData.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(PhoneBook)))
    {
        data.push_back(temp);
    }
//...
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        outData.write((char*)&data[i], sizeof(PhoneBook));
    }
```

Проблема в том, что в файл записываются вместе со значениями полей лишние символы  ( и им подобные). Поясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить. Можно ли проводить чтение/запись с помощью методов read/write, но чтобы в файл записывались только значения полей? Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Если вам необходимо сохранить класс в текстовый файл, то правильным решением является сохранения файла в определенный формат (это может быть как JSON/XML, так и ваш собственный формат). Ваш способ `inData.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(PhoneBook))` является потенциально опасным, зависимым от расположения данных в файле и зависимым от платформы. Если у вас в ТЗ не стоит жесткого условия сохранять файл именно таким способом, то лучше использовать что-то еще

Answer (score 0):

Так можно поступать только со "старыми простыми данными" (POD) в стиле С. Странно, что у вас нет полного краха программы по обращению к некорректному адресу в памяти или чего еще. Чтобы подсказать, как правильно - надо знать, что у вас там внутри, в `PhoneBook`.

Как писать В общем случае - см. [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/650110/195342), например.

Ну, а если вас интересует, откуда лишнее в файле - так ведь если, например, у вас массив под C-строку из 100 байт, а строка из 5, то пишутся-то все 100 байт, а не 5 - `sizeof()`, как у вас написано. Вот и пишется 5 байт нужных и 95 - того, что просто в памяти лежит.

Comment: В классе лежат поля string sName;
 string sSurname;
 string sPatronymic;
 int iDayOfBirth;
 int iMonthOfBirth;
 int iYearOfBirth, которые необходимо записать в файл. Как правильно провести запись? Значения полей каждого элемента вектора должны записываться через пробел в одной строке. То есть, первый элемент на одной строке, второй элемент - на строке ниже и т.д.

Comment: Вы хотите текстовый вывод? Не советую - зачем вам лезть внутрь файла и читать, что там написано? Бинарный надежнее. Но если очень хотите - выводите каждое поле через `<<` - `outData << sName << " ";`, вводите через `>>` - только вот потом, когда  окажется случайно в каком-то поле пробел - вы замучаетесь разбираться, где же ошибка... `read` и `write` - не для такой работы.